# From Perl running batch script, Script expects STDIN

Tags: windows, perl, command-line-arguments

In Windows, I want to run a batch script in perl. This batch script wants two inputs from the user, but I want these inputs to come from the perl script. I've tried doing an echo  | batchscript but that only works for one input. Currently I'm implementing it like this:

```
chdir "C:\\folder\\folder\\folder";
`some batch script`;
`echo variable`;
`echo filename`;
```

Another way I tried:

```
chdir "C:\\folder\\folder\\folder";
`echo variable | some batch script`;
`echo filename`;
```

The variable and filename are the two inputs that the script prompts for before continuing. Neither works. Anything helps. Thanks

Comment: You say "shell" script but your sample code uses Windows-style directories. Do you mean to say "batch file"?

Comment: Yes. I did mean batch file. The perl script is being ran in Window's CMD.

Answer (score 1):

As the script reads from stdin:

```
my $script_out = qx(printf "%s\n" variable filename | script.sh);
```